# jQuery sortable with custom rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table with a lot of  following a hierarchical rule on classes : "categorie" > "family" > "group" > "item"

I want to implement the jQuery sortable widget on this table (tbody to be precise) BUT with custom rules that I don't get to make work :

- "item" should only be put on top or underneath another "item"
- "group" should only be put on top of anoter "group" or underneath a "family"
- "family" should only be put on top of another "families" or underneath a "categories"
- "category" should only be put on top of another "category"

To keep the hierarchy when sorting elements.

In other words, I looking for a function that tell to sortable during the drag "yes(no) you can(can't) drop here" and so display or not the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe not beautiful but it work :

```
        var isValidPlacement = true;
        $('#input-table tbody').sortable({
            placeholder: {
                element: function (currentItem) {
                    return $('<tr id="placeholder"/>')[0];
                },
                update: function (container, p) {
                    return;
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
                var currentLevel = $(placeholder).data('level');
                var prev = $(placeholder).prev();
                var next = $(placeholder).next();
                var prevLevel = prev ? prev.data('level') : 0;
                var nextLevel = next ? next.data('level') : 0;

                // If prevLevel > nextLevel
                //    then whe are at the end of a container
                //    so we can put an element of any level between those ones
                // Else if prevLevel < newtLevel
                //    then we are just at the begging of a container
                //    so we can only put an element of level == prevLevel + 1 == nextLevel
                // Finally if prevLevel == nextLevel
                //    then we are in the middle of a container
                //    so we can only put an element of level == prevLevel == nextLevel
                isValidPlacement = (
                           prevLevel > nextLevel 
                        && prevLevel >= currentLevel 
                        && currentLevel >= nextLevel
                        || 
                           prevLevel <= nextLevel 
                        && currentLevel === nextLevel);

                placeholder.style.visibility = isValidPlacement ? "" : "hidden";
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                if (!isValidPlacement) {
                    $(this).sortable("cancel");
                }
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

Where 'level' is the level of hierarchi (here : category => 1, family => 2 ...)